# How to use xsl:for-each to fetch input

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my input request. Since my input and XSLT are lengthy I made them short here. I will be getting nearly 10 ProductID's, and I have to fetch all of them without using `xsl:template match`, since I cannot use template as child element in my XSLT. How should I write this in XSLT to get the wanted output?

Input:

```
<ChannelPartnerMembershipProfile>
<Dimension actionCode="4 ">
                                <ProductID>10000091</ProductID>
                                <ReceiverProductID>800GB</ReceiverProductID>
                                <DimensionStatusCode>02</DimensionStatusCode>
                                <StartDate>2020-12-07</StartDate>
                                <EndDate>2023-12-19</EndDate>
                            </Dimension>
                            <Dimension actionCode="4 ">
                                <ProductID>10000085</ProductID>
                                <ReceiverProductID>50GB</ReceiverProductID>
                                <DimensionStatusCode>02</DimensionStatusCode>
                                <StartDate>2020-12-06</StartDate>
                                <EndDate>2023-12-25</EndDate>
                            </Dimension>
</ChannelPartnerMembershipProfile>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Dimension">
                    <eep:EemblInternalProduct>
                      <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::EndDate[1]"/>
                       <eep:EndDate> 
                     <xsl:value-of select="$EndDate"/>
                     </eep:EndDate>
                     <eep:Name>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$ReceiverProductID"/>
                       </eep:Name>
                       <eep:Part>
                           <xsl:value-of select="ProductID"/>
                      </eep:Part>
                       <eep:StartDate>
                         <xsl:value-of select="$StartDate"/>
                      </eep:StartDate>
                      </eep:EemblInternalProduct>
                     </xsl:for-each>
```

My Expected Output:

```
<eep:EemblInternalProduct>
                     <eep:EndDate>2023-12-19</eep:EndDate>
                     <eep:Name>800GB</eep:Name>
                     <eep:Part>10000091</eep:Part>
                     <eep:StartDate>2020-12-07</eep:StartDate>
                  </eep:EemblInternalProduct>
                  <eep:EemblInternalProduct>
                     <eep:EndDate>2023-12-25</eep:EndDate>
                     <eep:Name>50GB</eep:Name>
                     <eep:Part>10000085</eep:Part>
                     <eep:StartDate>2020-12-06</eep:StartDate>
                  </eep:EemblInternalProduct>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to write it without using "template match" since I cannot use template as child element in my xslt.

Not a problem. You don't need to nest `<xsl:template>` at all. That's what `<xsl:apply-templates>` is for.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <list>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Dimension" />
    </list>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Dimension">
    <eep:EemblInternalProduct>
        <eep:EndDate> 
            <xsl:value-of select="EndDate" />
        </eep:EndDate>
        <eep:Name>
            <xsl:value-of select="ReceiverProductID" />
        </eep:Name>
        <eep:Part>
            <xsl:value-of select="ProductID" />
        </eep:Part>
        <eep:StartDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="StartDate" />
        </eep:StartDate>
    </eep:EemblInternalProduct>
</xsl:template>
```

results in

```
<list xmlns:eep="...">
    <eep:EemblInternalProduct>
        <eep:EndDate>2023-12-19</eep:EndDate>
        <eep:Name>800GB</eep:Name>
        <eep:Part>10000091</eep:Part>
        <eep:StartDate>2020-12-07</eep:StartDate>
    </eep:EemblInternalProduct>
    <eep:EemblInternalProduct>
        <eep:EndDate>2023-12-25</eep:EndDate>
        <eep:Name>50GB</eep:Name>
        <eep:Part>10000085</eep:Part>
        <eep:StartDate>2020-12-06</eep:StartDate>
    </eep:EemblInternalProduct>
</list>
```

Note that

- `<xsl:apply-templates>` replaces the `<xsl:for-each>`.
- `<xsl:value-of select="$EndDate" />` selects the value of the *variable* `$EndDate`. You don't have such a variable. You want to select the value of the *element* `<EndDate>`. An that is done with `<xsl:value-of select="EndDate" />`.

Comment: Hi Tom, I tried with apply-templates, still not getting desired output..I;m posting my error link..please check

Comment: @nikki The link you have posted has literally nothing to do with your question, it does not contain `<xsl:apply-templates>` and there is no error.

Comment: Please check now..I posted wrong link..sorry.

Comment: @nikki OMG what is this? That's... not how XSLT is supposed to be used. :o I hate to say it, but you need to throw all of that away and start from scratch.

Comment: Tom, The code is written according to the requirement. Can you please help where should I make changes in XSLT ? If you scroll my xslt code from top you will see that specific code which I posted here. For-each loop is not working and this is an urgent requirement. Please help.

Comment: @nikki I mean it. This is unsalvagable. It's fractally wrong. I am aware that it must have been *a lot* of work to get where you are, but it's not worth it continuing this way. I can help you get started by rewriting a part of it to show you what you should have been doing, but I'm afraid you need to start over.

Comment: There's two options. **a)** You can start over with code that is not completely insane, or **b)** I can't help you. I won't touch this code and "make it work".

Comment: It's working now with <xsl:apply-templates> as expected. Thankyou ! :)

Comment: @nikki Good for you, but your XSLT is still unsalvageable. A better approach is this: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGF/1.

Comment: OMG Tom ! Awesome. Thankyou !

Comment: @nikki I hope it contains things you can use and things you can learn. :)

Comment: Yeah, this approach is completely new to me, bit confusing but I learned something new...

Comment: @nikki There's probably more room for improvement, because I don't know your business requirements and input document characteristics. But it's less repetitive, less deeply nested, has higher re-usability and is overall a lot easier to maintain. It's the way XSLT should be written. Try to build on it.

Comment: Thankyou Tom ! Will apply it.